# Relationship does not exist in SQL

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I sent a command to the database

```
INSERT INTO UserEntity(id, username, email, password, enabled, registration_date, modified_date)
SELECT
    1, 'JonkiPro', 'someemail@someemail.com,', 'safsd', true, GetDate(), GetDate()
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'JonkiPro'
);
```

which is to add a new user to the database. Cherry during compilation throws out the error

`ERROR: relationship "userentity" does not exist`
I am in the application created entity '`UserEntity`' which represents the user with an annotation added `@Table(name="users")`?

How do I make a mistake when creating this query?

Comment: If the table name is `users`, then the SQL needs to start `INSERT INTO users ...`.  The name `UserEntity` might be your Java class, but it won't be recognised by your database.

Comment: Could you show the java code where you use these?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty clear your error code. Basically you are trying to insert some data in a table `userentity` that doesn't exist in your database schema. (In SQL, tables = relationships).

You just have to **put the name of your database table that you want to insert into or create a table named `userentity`.**